# How to pass array to ajax post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this `AJAX` post script:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: '/products',
  data: { product[order_id]:order_id, product[product_id]:product_id, product[count]:count },
  type: 'post',
  success: function(result){
     // $('.resultMessage').text(result);
  }
})
```

And it gives me this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [` - how could I fix this?

Comment: dupe:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277439/how-to-send-an-javascript-array-to-php-via-jquery-ajax

Comment: Notice: you can't get value of associative arrays in javascript like this  product[product_id] here product_id know as a variable ,quotation or double quotation are required for  associative arrays  product["product_id"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not valid JSON. Try this:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: '/products',
  data: { 
            product: {
                order_id: order_id,
                product_id: product_id,
                count: count
            }
         },
  type: 'post',
  success: function(result){
     // $('.resultMessage').text(result);
  }
})
```

And you'd access it like this:

```
var myOrderId = data.product.order_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
product_array = // array with key and value pair.

var productString = JSON.stringify(product_array);
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data: {data : productString}, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
    });
```

and php code as follow

```
$post_data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

// and using foreach you can get key or value as follow.

foreach ($post_data as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    echo $value;
}
```